# Binding object of UserControl to parent Form in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, user-controls

I have a windows c# app in winforms with a main form and a userControl.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
   //myPanel is an instance of the user control
   public Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      myCheckBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", myPanel.buildParameters, "isChecked");
   }
}
public partial class PublicationPanel : UserControl
{
    public BuildParameters buildParameters = new BuildParameters ();

    public PublicationPanel()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        buildParameters.isChecked= true;
        buildParameters.Project = "";
        buildParameters.Version = "";

        ProjectList.DataBindings.Add("Text", buildParameters, "Project");
        VersionText.DataBindings.Add("Text", buildParameters, "Version");
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
public class BuildParameters : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool isChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked= value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("isChecked"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the checkbox is binded correctly when the form loads. The checkbox is checked. But when I uncheck the checkbox and after I change the value of a field (projetList or versionText lost focus) in the userControl, the checkox become again checked.

The binding in userControl works well.

Have an idea of what happens?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edit the post. Thanks

Comment: Why did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: It's an example I found on the web. What's the best way to bind an object?

Comment: It's the Checked property of the checkBox in the main form.